# Using randomUUID() in Zapier to generate UUID

Tags: node.js, zapier

I'm using Zapier's code module to write some Nodejs to generate a UUID.

I know that I can use node's crypto "library" because I've used it in the past to hash some text (MD5) to send to an API endpoint. I also know that I can use the crypto function randomInt.

For example, the following will correctly without errors return a number in the stated range:

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); 
let num = crypto.randomInt(1, 7);
output = [{id: num}];
```

When I try to use the randomUUID function ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomuuid_options)), like the following, I get the error "TypeError: crypto.randomUUID is not a function" from Zapier:

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); 
let uuid = crypto.randomUUID();
output = [{id: uuid}];
```

I almost gave up there, but tried one last weird thing:

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); 
let uuid = crypto.randomUUID; //changed this
output = [{id: uuid}];
```

Note that I removed the `()` and this didn't throw an error and returned something like:

`LT6TvivKgpFu5Yk3OvQmti1Hq1aNy5ZM`

That looks a lot like a proper UUID since it has the right number of characters, but not the expected hyphens like (for example) `88368f2a-d5db-47d8-a05f-534fab0a0045`

So, two questions:

- Why is Zapier saying that `randomUUID()` is not a function? Does it not support this or am I coding something weirdly wrong or not requiring something needed? Is there a different way to do this?
- When I use `randomUUID` (no `()`) is this actually a reliable UUID?

EDIT: more info from Zapier, they are saying that their logs show that the code step cannot find `module 'uuid'`

Answer (score 1):

> When I use randomUUID (no ()) is this actually a reliable UUID?

The value you're getting there is not a reliable UUID. UUIDs will contain only 0-9a-f characters, the example you have there doesn't match.

Sorry I can't help you with what's going wrong with the other part! You could maybe try something like this

```
let crypto;
try {
  crypto = require('crypto');
} catch (err) {
  console.log('crypto support is disabled!');
}
```

to make sure the `crypto` package is actually available and there's not some error being silently suppressed? You may also want to check the version, as `randomUUID()` appears to have been added in v14.17.0

Also nit but should probably be `const uuid = crypto.randomUUID();` instead of `let` ;)

Comment: Very valuable. Thanks. Good to have confirmation on that UUID. Crypto is definitely available, as I've used that before and its `randomInt` function works fine. Something odd about `randomUUID` though.

Comment: @jonmrich If you used `randomUUID` function before, that could be on different integration version. Check app version and `nodejs` engine version in your `package.json` and `zapier push` again.

Comment: I haven't used `randomUUID` before, but I have used other `crypto` functions like `randomInt`

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this post looking for a way to generate a random UUID from within a Zapier Code step.  While none of what's on this page actually worked for me, I was able to find a solution.  I wanted to share it in case it helps someone else.

```
import uuid

# Generate a random UUID
random_uuid = uuid.uuid4()

# Convert the UUID to a string
random_uuid_str = str(random_uuid)

print(random_uuid_str)
```